# Redux framework, Wordpress, Select page/post from all post types

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I'm using Redux and I want select one post/page form select list. But I want choose form some post types (or all).
This is my Redux code for this field.

```
        'fields'     => array(
            array(
                'id'       => 'featured_post_type',
                'type'     => 'select',
                'multi'    => false,
                'data'      => 'pages',
                'args' => array('post_type' => array('nyheter_grenene', 'nyheter_forbundet', 'stup') ),
                'title'    => __('Featured Post', TD),
                'subtitle' => __('Selected post will be displayed in page top menu', TD),
                //'desc'     => __('Page will be marked as front for this post type', TD),
            ),
       ),
```

Comment: Ask here: https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that you have to change in your code so that it works properly. Here's a working version:

```
'fields'     => array(
    array(
        'id'       => 'featured_post_type',
        'type'     => 'select',
        'multi'    => false,
        'data'     => 'posts',
        'args'     => array( 'post_type' =>  array( 'nyheter_grenene', 'nyheter_forbundet', 'stup' ), 'numberposts' => -1 ),
        'title'    => __( 'Featured Post', TD ),
        'subtitle' => __( 'Selected post will be displayed in page top menu', TD ),
        //'desc'     => __( 'Page will be marked as front for this post type', TD ),
    ),
),
```

The difference here is that we have `'data' => 'posts'`(instead of `pages`) and we also added `'numberposts' => -1` to the `args` array.

When you use `'data' => 'pages'`, the function `[get_pages()][1]` is used, which only supports hierarchical post types.